# JAVA Cartesian shape plotter

Tags: java, algorithm, methods, procedural-programming, cartesian-coordinates

I am trying to create a java program that will accept inputs from the user to draw a single star (*) rectangle within the grid. I want the program to accept the (x, y) coordinate pair of the top left corner of the rectangle, along with the rectangle’s width and height. It should then draw the rectangle like this Ex. (x = 16, y = 14) and (width = 4, height = 5). I'm struggling with where to approach this as I am trying to do it without using arrays or 2d arrays for drawing the rectangle and cartesian grid.

How would I go about dividing up the cohesive methods I need to draw a 20x40 grid, and then draw a shape onto that grid without messing up the grid by drawing it?

Any tips/code to get my gears turning would be appreciated.

(no experience with special libraries either, so this has to be pretty vanilla java)

```
    
   Y
   ^
20 +
   |
   |
   |
   |
15 +
   |                 ****
   |                 ****
   |                 ****
   |                 ****                                   
10 +                 ****
   | 
   | 
   | 
   | 
 5 + 
   | 
   |
   |
   |
   0 +====+====+====+====+====+====+====+====+ >X
     0    5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to print this to the console, not on some GUI?

Comment: In that case, I'd probably model screen with a 2D array of `char`, to have a mutable structure the different methods can write to. The printing would only happen when the frame is fully calculated.

Comment: Yes, just print to console for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare StringBuilder from constant string with empty grid of spaces (with Intellij Idea it is one copypasta of your example, or with Java 15+ you can use text blocks).
2. Replace space subsequences by asterisk subsequences in loop.

Comment: How would each stringbuilder correspond with a y value? Not familiar with text blocks.

Comment: You would essentially call `stringbuilder.replace(start,start+width,"*".repeat(width))` in loop for `i` from `y` to `y-height`. Your task is to compute `start` index which is some linear function of `i`, `x` and total width. Or create array of stringbuilders and then join them. You don't necessarily need to know Java 15 text blocks for completing this task.